# one path with multiple components divide by type of content

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, redux-saga

Can I use the same path with different component?

For example,

```
<Route exact path="/add/:addId" component={AddIdAType} />
<Route exact path="/add/:addId" component={AddIdBType} />
```

and my code is about this

```
      goPage(type){
   switch(type){
     case 'a' :
      return <AddIdAType />
     default:
     return <AddIdBType />
   }
 }

render(){
   let go= this.goPage(this.props.type);

    return (

      <Link to={`/add/${add.id}/`}  component={go}>
        ........

      </Link>
```

This way is not correct, so what should I can do to go to different component but same path (component={go} is ERROR)

If someone know about it, please help me to fix it out

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single Route using the render method of Route.

```
<Route exact 
   path="/add/:addId" 
   render={(props)=>{
      let id = props.match.params['addId']; //i guess you would use this field in the child components
      switch(this.props.type){
        case 'a' :
          return <AddIdAType addId={id}/>
        default:
           return <AddIdBType addId={id} />
   }
   }} />
```

Comment: for the <Route /> I use in different file and not sent any parameter in that file, so I cant do like you suggest

Comment: Link does not take component as prop. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link  You need to use Route instead of Link.

Comment: I cant get in with your link

Comment: I compare between Link and Route in the file which I refer when click